# Enabling Async in Sitecore Controller Renderings

Tags: c#, asynchronous, controller, sitecore, sitecore8

I created an async controller but I think Sitecore 8 does not support it. Is there any way out to fix this issue. I tried the following: http://kamsar.net/index.php/2015/05/Enabling-Async-in-Sitecore-Controller-Renderings/ but it does not work.

Comment: What exactly does not work? If you be more specific people might be able to guide u to this proces.

Comment: Did you see this notice in that post: `The information in this post unfortunately does NOT work for controller renderings as I had originally thought.` - how are you calling your async controller action?

Answer (score 5):

As of March 2017, it looks like [Sitecore does not support async controller renderings](https://sitecorecommunity.uservoice.com/forums/286986-product-sitecore-mvc/suggestions/7321868-async-support) and has no immediate plans to do so.

In order to avoid deadlocks, applications using the async/await pattern [should not mix synchronous and asynchronous code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). The Sitecore APIs are currently synchronous, so async controller renderings would result in potential deadlocks until Sitecore gets their shit together.